# How to assign cell value to a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to get some cell value and assign it to a variable.

Vars 'result' and 'result2' are two Long values that contains which row and column the value I'm looking for is. I've checked and the numbers match on the table but when I run the code it says

> Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error".

Here's what I got:

```
For row = 1 To countRows
    brand = Sheets("2017").Cells(row, 1)
    If InStr(strSaida, brand) Then
        result2 = row
    End If
Next row

For col = 2 To countCol
    mes = Sheets("2017").Cells(2, col)
    If InStr(strProcMes, mes) Then
        result = col
    End If
Next col

Dim cellValor As Long
cellValor = Sheets("2017").Range(Cells(result2, result)).Value
```

Comment: where are result and result2 defined?

Comment: drop the .range 2nd line should be ... cellValor = Sheets("2017").Cells(result2, result).Value

Comment: @SEarle1986 I edited the code

Comment: @KneeColas Thanks it worked!!! How do I mark your answer as the solution? I barely use stackoverflow

Comment: You can upvote the comment - thanks. If you're not able to (not sure if you need certain reputation to upvote comments) - no worries. Happy to help

Comment: @KneeColas You should post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem line

```
cellValor = Sheets("2017").Range(Cells(result2, result)).Value
```

It should be

```
cellValor = Sheets("2017").Cells(result2, result).Value
```